# Which version of excision theorem should be used to solve this problem ? why?how?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, proof-writing, homology-cohomology

Use excision to prove that for all $n,$ $H_{n}(\mathbb{R}^k, \mathbb{R}^k - \{0\} ) \cong H_{n}({D}^k, {D}^k - \{0\} ). $

And the statement of excision theorem is given below:

> [image]

**My question is:**

Which version of excision theorem should be used to solve this problem ? why?how?

**My trial is:**

I am guessing it is the first version but I do not know exactly why. My approch is $X = \mathbb{R}^k,$ $A = \mathbb{R}^k \setminus \{0\}$ and then I do not know what is $Z.$

Could anyone help me in understanding the above?

Comment: Well, let's just try with the first version. If you want to reproduce the given statement, you better have $X\setminus Z=D^n$, $A\setminus Z=D^n\setminus\{0\}$, right? What choice of $Z$ does that suggest?

Comment: Similarly, taking your choices for $X$ and $A$ in the second version, what $B$ are we looking for to get the initial statement?

Comment: Is $Z = \{0\}$ ?@Danu

Comment: What would that give you for $X\setminus Z$?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^k \setminus \{0\}$ @Danu

Comment: Yeah, and that's *not* what you want. You want $X\setminus Z=D^n$.

Comment: so it should be $\mathbb{R}^k \setminus D^n$ @Danu .... correct?

Comment: Does it give you the correct set for $A\setminus Z$ too? If it does, then you should be able to convince yourself whether it is correct.

Comment: I think I am correct @Danu ..... correct? :)))

Comment: You should consider writing an answer to your own question, so that it can be accepted and the question will not be left 'unanswered'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it as you want. As you say, we have $X = \mathbb{R}^k,$ $A = \mathbb{R}^k \setminus \{0\}$. You can

1. either excise $Z = \mathbb R^k \setminus \text{int}D^k$ (which is closed and contained in the open set $A$)
2. or take $B = D^k$ and use the second isomorphism.